# 502 Bad Gateway Error when trying to make a request to ANEEL API using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, api

I'm having an issue with the ANEEL API query through a macro in an Excel spreadsheet. Although I can successfully make the request in a browser, I'm unable to write some fields in the Excel table due to a 502 Bad Gateway error. I'm investigating what might be causing this issue.

I'm trying to create a VBA macro to make a request to the ANEEL API and retrieve the desired data. I've written the following function:

```
Sub ConsultAPI()
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim response As String
    Dim json As Object
    Dim utilityCompany As String
    Dim tariffGroup As String

    ' Get the utility company name from the desired cell
    utilityCompany = Sheets("Start").Range("B21").Value
    
    ' Get the tariff group
    tariffGroup = Sheets("Start").Range("B27").Value
    
    ' Get the tariff class
    tariffClass = Sheets("Start").Range("B19").Value
    
    ' Get the value from cell B20 as the filter for subclass
    Dim subclassFilter As String
    subclassFilter = Sheets("Start").Range("B20").Value
    
    ' Replace whitespace with %20 in the utility company string
    utilityCompany = Replace(utilityCompany, " ", "%20")
    
    ' Replace whitespace with %20 in the tariff group string
    tariffGroup = Replace(tariffGroup, " ", "%20")
    
    ' Replace whitespace with %20 in the class (DscClasse) string
    tariffClass = Replace(tariffClass, " ", "%20")
    
    ' Replace whitespace with %20 in the subclass string
    subclassFilter = Replace(subclassFilter, " ", "%20")
    
    ' Add a filter for the DscSubClasse field in the URL
    Dim filterDscSubClasse As String
    filterDscSubClasse = "%20AND%20%22DscSubClasse%22%20%3D%20%27" & subclassFilter & "%27"
    
    ' Add a filter for the DscModalidadeTarifaria field in the URL
    Dim filterDscModalidadeTarifaria As String
    filterDscModalidadeTarifaria = "%20AND%20%22DscModalidadeTarifaria%22%20%3D%20%27Convencional%27"
    
    ' Add the filter for the NomPostoTarifario field in the URL
    url = "https://dadosabertos.aneel.gov.br/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20%22fcf2906c-7c32-4b9b-a637-054e7a5234f4%22%20WHERE%20%22SigAgente%22%20%3D%20%27" & utilityCompany & "%27%20AND%20%22DscSubGrupo%22%20%3D%20%27" & tariffGroup & "%27%20AND%20%22DscClasse%22%20%3D%20%27" & tariffClass & "%27%20AND%20%22SigAgenteAcessante%22%20IN%20(%27NA%27,%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27)%20AND%20%22DscBaseTarifaria%22%20%3D%20%27Tarifa%20de%20Aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o%27" & filterDscSubClasse & filterDscModalidadeTarifaria & "%20AND%20%22NomPostoTarifario%22%20%3D%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27%20ORDER%20BY%20%22DatInicioVigencia%22%20DESC%20LIMIT%201"

    ' Save the request details before making the GET request
    SaveRequestDetails url

    ' Initialize the xmlhttp object
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    ' Make the GET request to the API
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", url, False
    xmlhttp.send
    
    ' Check the API response status
    If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then
        ' Parse the returned JSON
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(xmlhttp.responseText)

        ' Check if the "success" field is true
        If json("success") = True Then
            ' The query was successful, retrieve the result
            Dim records As Object
            Set records = json("result")("records")

            ' Check if there are any returned records
            If records.Count > 0 Then
                ' Get the latest record
                Dim record As Object
                Set record = records(1)

                ' Access the fields and assign the values to Excel cells as needed
                
                Sheets("Start").Range("B23").Value = record("DscREH")
                Sheets("Start").Range("B24").Value = record("DatInicioVigencia")
                Sheets("Start").Range("B25").Value = record("DatFimVigencia")
                
                Sheets("Start").Range("B28").Value = record("VlrTUSD")
                Sheets("Start").Range("B29").Value = record("VlrTE")
                
                ' ...
                ' Assign other fields and cells as needed
            Else
                MsgBox "No records found."
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Query failed: " & json("error")
        End If
    Else
        ' The request failed, display the error message
        MsgBox "API request failed! Status: " & xmlhttp.Status & " Response: " & xmlhttp.responseText
    End If
    
    ' Release the xmlhttp object
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
End Sub
```

This macro is making the following API request:

https://dadosabertos.aneel.gov.br/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20%22fcf2906c-7c32-4b9b-a637-054e7a5234f4%22%20WHERE%20%22SigAgente%22%20%3D%20%27Equatorial%20AL%27%20AND%20%22DscSubGrupo%22%20%3D%20%27B3%27%20AND%20%22DscClasse%22%20%3D%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27%20AND%20%22SigAgenteAcessante%22%20IN%20(%27NA%27,%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27)%20AND%20%22DscBaseTarifaria%22%20%3D%20%27Tarifa%20de%20Aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o%27%20AND%20%22DscSubClasse%22%20%3D%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27%20AND%20%22DscModalidadeTarifaria%22%20%3D%20%27Convencional%27%20AND%20%22NomPostoTarifario%22%20%3D%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27%20ORDER%20BY%20%22DatInicioVigencia%22%20DESC%20LIMIT%201

When testing the request in a browser, I can verify that it is working as expected and returning the following response:

```
// 20230605160415
// https://dadosabertos.aneel.gov.br/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20%22fcf2906c-7c32-4b9b-a637-054e7a5234f4%22%20WHERE%20%22SigAgente%22%20%3D%20%27Equatorial%20AL%27%20AND%20%22DscSubGrupo%22%20%3D%20%27B3%27%20AND%20%22DscClasse%22%20%3D%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27%20AND%20%22SigAgenteAcessante%22%20IN%20(%27NA%27,%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27)%20AND%20%22DscBaseTarifaria%22%20%3D%20%27Tarifa%20de%20Aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o%27%20AND%20%22DscSubClasse%22%20%3D%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27%20AND%20%22DscModalidadeTarifaria%22%20%3D%20%27Convencional%27%20AND%20%22NomPostoTarifario%22%20%3D%20%27N%C3%A3o%20se%20aplica%27%20ORDER%20BY%20%22DatInicioVigencia%22%20DESC%20LIMIT%201

{
  "help": "https://dadosabertos.aneel.gov.br/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_search_sql",
  "success": true,
  "result": {
    "sql": "SELECT * FROM \"fcf2906c-7c32-4b9b-a637-054e7a5234f4\" WHERE \"SigAgente\" = 'Equatorial AL' AND \"DscSubGrupo\" = 'B3' AND \"DscClasse\" = 'Não se aplica' AND \"SigAgenteAcessante\" IN ('NA', 'Não se aplica') AND \"DscBaseTarifaria\" = 'Tarifa de Aplicação' AND \"DscSubClasse\" = 'Não se aplica' AND \"DscModalidadeTarifaria\" = 'Convencional' AND \"NomPostoTarifario\" = 'Não se aplica' ORDER BY \"DatInicioVigencia\" DESC LIMIT 1",
    "records": [
      {
        "_id": 221157,
        "_full_text": "'-02':22 '-05':3,18,21 '-06':2 '-28':19 '12272084000100':16 '19':47 '2023':1,13,17 '2024':20 '24':9 '3.203':7 '304':46 '561':44 '83':45 'al':15 'aplica':30,33,36,39,43 'aplicação':25 'b3':26 'convencion':27 'de':8,10,12,24 'equatori':14 'homologatória':5 'maio':11 'mwh':40 'nº':6 'não':28,31,34,37,41 'resolução':4 'se':29,32,35,38,42 'tarifa':23",
        "DatGeracaoConjuntoDados": "2023-06-05",
        "DscREH": "RESOLUÇÃO HOMOLOGATÓRIA Nº 3.203, DE 24 DE MAIO DE 2023",
        "SigAgente": "Equatorial AL",
        "NumCNPJDistribuidora": "12272084000100",
        "DatInicioVigencia": "2023-05-28",
        "DatFimVigencia": "2024-05-02",
        "DscBaseTarifaria": "Tarifa de Aplicação",
        "DscSubGrupo": "B3",
        "DscModalidadeTarifaria": "Convencional",
        "DscClasse": "Não se aplica",
        "DscSubClasse": "Não se aplica",
        "DscDetalhe": "Não se aplica",
        "NomPostoTarifario": "Não se aplica",
        "DscUnidadeTerciaria": "MWh",
        "SigAgenteAcessante": "Não se aplica",
        "VlrTUSD": "561,83",
        "VlrTE": "304,19"
      }
    ],
    "fields": [
      {
        "id": "_id",
        "type": "int4"
      },
      {
        "id": "_full_text",
        "type": "tsvector"
      },
      {
        "id": "DatGeracaoConjuntoDados",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "id": "DscREH",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "id": "SigAgente",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "id": "NumCNPJDistribuidora",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "id": "DatInicioVigencia",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "id": "DatFimVigencia",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "id": "DscBaseTarifaria",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "id": "DscSubGrupo",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "id": "DscModalidadeTarifaria",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "id": "DscClasse",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "id": "DscSubClasse",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "id": "DscDetalhe",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "id": "NomPostoTarifario",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "id": "DscUnidadeTerciaria",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "id": "SigAgenteAcessante",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "id": "VlrTUSD",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "id": "VlrTE",
        "type": "text"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, when I try to use the macro in Excel through the VBA editor, I receive this message:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>502 Bad Gateway </title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <center>
       <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
     </center>
       <hr>
     <center>nginx/1.18.0(Ubuntu)
     </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me - re-arranged to be a little more readable:

```vb
Sub ConsultAPI()
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim url As String, qs As String
    Dim response As String
    Dim json As Object
    Dim utilityCompany As String
    Dim tariffGroup As String, tariffClass As String
    Dim subclassFilter As String, wsStart As Worksheet
    
    Set wsStart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Start")
    utilityCompany = wsStart.Range("B21").Value ' utility company name
    tariffGroup = wsStart.Range("B27").Value ' tariff group
    tariffClass = wsStart.Range("B19").Value ' tariff class
    subclassFilter = wsStart.Range("B20").Value
    
    url = "https://dadosabertos.aneel.gov.br/api/3/action/datastore_search_sql?sql="
    qs = "SELECT * FROM ""fcf2906c-7c32-4b9b-a637-054e7a5234f4"" WHERE " & _
            " ""SigAgente"" = '" & utilityCompany & "' AND " & _
            " ""DscSubGrupo"" = '" & tariffGroup & "' AND " & _
            " ""DscClasse"" = '" & tariffClass & "' AND " & _
            " ""SigAgenteAcessante"" IN ('NA', 'Não se aplica') AND " & _
            " ""DscBaseTarifaria"" = 'Tarifa de Aplicação' AND " & _
            " ""DscSubClasse"" = '" & subclassFilter & "' AND " & _
            " ""DscModalidadeTarifaria"" = 'Convencional' AND " & _
            " ""NomPostoTarifario"" = 'Não se aplica' ORDER BY ""DatInicioVigencia"" DESC LIMIT 1"

    url = url & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(qs) 'encode the SQL (Excel 2013 on)
    
    ' Save the request details before making the GET request
    'SaveRequestDetails url

    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", url, False
    xmlhttp.send 'OK from this point...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was having a lot of difficulty understanding how concatenation of elements worked in VBA, and your code helped me a lot in understanding how it works.